# phpmailer error SMTP Error: Data not accepted

Tags: javascript, php, smtp, phpmailer

I've searched all the solutions on StackOverflow for this and tried everything but can't seem to fix this error. It seems to be intermittent as occasionally it works and I receive the email and attachments into my MSOutlook inbox making this even more frustrating.

I'm using phpmailer to send image files (jpg)

Here's mail-send.php

```
<?php
require('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Port     = 465;
$mail->Username = "NAME@DOMAIN.ORG";
$mail->Password = "PASSWORD";
$mail->Host     = "mail.uk2.net";
$mail->Mailer   = "smtp";
$mail->SetFrom($_POST["userEmail"], $_POST["userName"]);
$mail->AddReplyTo($_POST["userEmail"], $_POST["userName"]);
$mail->AddAddress("NAME@DOMAIN.ORG");   
$mail->Subject = $_POST["subject"];
$mail->WordWrap   = 80;
$mail->MsgHTML($_POST["content"]);

foreach ($_FILES["attachment"]["name"] as $k => $v) {
    $mail->AddAttachment( $_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"][$k], $_FILES["attachment"]["name"][$k] );
}

$mail->IsHTML(true);

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "<p class='error'>There was a problem sending your photographs. Please try again later via your 'My Dashboard' homepage.</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p class='success'><strong>Your photograph/s have been submitted.</strong><br>Thank you!</p>";
}   
?>
```

and here's the html form in send.php

```
<form id="sendpics" action="" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <input name="userName" type="text" id="userName" value="<?php echo $row['rFullName']; ?>">
            <input name="userEmail" type="text" id="userEmail" value="<?php echo $row['rEmail']; ?>">
            <input name="subject" type="text" id="subject" value="Photos for CBC Record ID <?php echo htmlentities($row['rID']); ?>">
                
            <textarea name="content" id="content" rows="6">
            <?php echo htmlentities($row['rFullName']); ?> has submitted a record.
            <br>Photos relating to this record are attached.
            <br>Record ID#: <?php echo htmlentities($row["rID"]); ?>
            <br>Location: <?php echo htmlentities($row['rLocation']); ?>
            <br>Date: <?php echo htmlentities($row['rDate']); ?>
            <br><a href='URL?rID=<?php echo htmlentities($row["rID"]); ?>'>Click this link</a>* to view this record.</textarea>
                              
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <input class="form-control" type="file" name="attachment[]" multiple="multiple" accept=".jpg,.jpeg">
            </div>
                
            <div id="loader-icon" style="display: none;" class="pull-right"><img src="LoaderIcon.gif" /></div><input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" value="SEND PHOTOS" />
                
</form>
<div id="mail-status"></div>
```

and the script in the head of send.php

```
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (e){
    $("#sendpics").on('submit',(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#loader-icon').show();
        var valid;  
        valid = validateContact();
        if(valid) {
            $.ajax({
            url: "mail-send.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:  new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data){
                $("#mail-status").html(data);
                $('#loader-icon').hide();
            },
            error: function(){}             
        });
    }
    }));
});
</script>
```

Any phpmailer genius out there know what I'm doing wrong to get

> SMTP Error: Data not accepted'

most but not all of the time? Yesterday it seemed to be working fine. Today the only change on the server is that we now have an SSL certificate. Could this be the cause? If so, the fix?? We are on UK2.net hosting.

Huge thanks in advance.
Steve

Comment: I am not totally sure of my ground here, but you appear to be leaving the files on the TMP area where PHP puts them for you to deal with. PHP will delete these files when this script completes. Is it possible that sometimes the files have been removed before the mail server has actually gathered up the files.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php Try "completing" the upload process. Use [is_uploaded_file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) and [move_uploaded_file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php), could be your temporary files are removed or the mailsending process is initialized when the files have not yet been uploaded completely

Comment: `It seems to be intermittent as occasionally it works` .... likely its your hosting provider's fault. Have you opened a ticket with them?

Comment: Firstly, you’re using a very old version of PHPMailer, so upgrade. Next, you’re not handling the upload safely: base your code on the send file upload example provided with PHPMailer. Beyond that, what the others said.